# Angular Material Dialog Unwanted inline style

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to use Angular Material Dialog and override some styles without using "!important" in my CSS.

Angular Material injects cdk-overlay-pane with an inline style like this:

```
<div id="cdk-overlay-0" class="cdk-overlay-pane" style="max-width:80vw; pointer-events: auto; position: static;">
```

Is it possible to configure Angular Material so that it doesn't add these inline styles?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible this wasn't available when you asked the question, but you can now specify a blank value for min-width when the dialog is opened, which will prevent Angular Material from injecting the 80vw.

```
this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
  maxWidth: ''
});
```

The documentation for the config object can be found here: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig

I'm not sure about the pointer-events or position properties, but you may be able to play with the various configuration options to find something that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can configure that, but you can target it using `::ng-deep`

For Example: (assuming you are writing SCSS)

```
::ng-deep{
    .cdk-overlay-pane{
        min-width: 90vw;
    }
}
```

or even

```
/deep/ .cdk-overlay-pane{
  min-width: 90vw
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But specificity cannot override inline-styles. Only !important can which I would rather avoid.

Answer (score 0):

If you find that there is no way to escape using `!important` and there is no other way, you can minimize it's impact with `:is(.my-custom-class)`.

For example:

```
:is(.my-custom-class) .cdk-overlay-pane{
  min-width: 90vw !important;
}
```

Then in your code control the `.my-custom-class` with `ngClass`:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'my-custom-class': triggerOnDemand}">
```

were `triggerOnDemand` is a variable you control in your component as needed

If `:is` is not supported by the browser you may use `:any` but it requires specific browser support such as `:-webkit-any` etc'.

More details can be found on MDN site (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is)

Note that deep, although working, is deprecated (https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)